# Mobile Push: TimeInApp value in the Push Message Detail report

Tags: mobile, mobilepush, push-notification

I'm trying to figure out what's stored inside TimeInApp value in the Push Message Detail report. I'm pretty much sure that the value contains the time the users spent in the app after opening the message, but I'm not sure about the unit of the time here. Is it milliseconds or just seconds?

To help you get much clearer idea about this, I attached the image of the record.

[image]

It's hard to find a clear answer since there're no offical docs about the record type of push message details report. The information presented on HELP only tells about the meaning of each field,which still was not a clear answer.
If anyone can share some opinions about this, it would be a huge help. Just guess woud be okay too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure that's seconds as that's what we send from the SDKs.

Comment: Just a heads up that this got into the "Low Quality Posts" queue. I'm marking it as ok because I know you're an authoritative source on mobile/sdk things.

Comment: Thanks Derek. The answer of "yep, that's right" isn't ideal for sure :)